# Загрузка файла без клика ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть js скрипт который загружает выбранный файл по клику на `#uploadImage`.

Нужно чтоб файл загружался без нажатия, сразу после выбора файла.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" class="file-styled" name="image" multiple="multiple" accept=".txt,image/*"><button class="btn bg-slate" id="uploadImage">Загрузить</button>
```

JS:

```
(function($){

    var files;
    $('input[type=file]').on('change', function(){
        files = this.files;
    });

    $('#uploadImage').on( 'click', function( event ){

        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        if( typeof files == 'undefined' ) return;

        var data = new FormData();
        $.each( files, function( key, value ){
            data.append( key, value );
        });

        data.append( 'uploadImage', 1 );

        $.ajax({
            url         : window.location.href,
            type        : 'POST',
            data        : data,
            cache       : false,
            dataType    : 'json',
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
            success     : function( respond, status, jqXHR ){

                if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
                    var files_path = respond.files;
                    var html = 'Файл успешно загружен';
                    $('.ajax-reply').html( html );
                }
                else {
                    console.log('ОШИБКА: ' + respond.error );
                }
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, status, errorThrown ){
                console.log( 'ОШИБКА AJAX запроса: ' + status, jqXHR );
            }

        });

    });


})(jQuery)
```

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: `$('#uploadImage').on( 'click', function( event ){` замените на `$('#uploadImage').on( 'change', function( event ){`

Comment: #uploadImage это и есть кнопка

Comment: Отправку производите здесь `$('input[type=file]').on('change', function(){`

Comment: Благодарю! работает.